# Partitioning win 10 for dual boot ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

HP Envy laptop, 16GB ram, 500GB SSD with Win 10 already installed.
Installing 20.04 and have to choose 'Something Else' since there is no option to install along side Windows. When partitioning the Windows C  partition (511316 MB), I get the Edit Partition box. I select about half the size of that partition for the size I want for Ubuntu but what should I select as the 'Use as' entry? Should it be Ext4 journaling, FAT32 or EFI System Partition?

Comment: You can take a look at [this website](https://www.pcsteps.com/3305-prepare-windows-dual-boot-installation/) on how to allocate disk space, and check out [the links](https://www.pcsteps.com/961-install-ubuntu-linux-windows/) within the web page too.

Comment: Do not use Ubuntu to work on Windows partition/s, use windows for best results.  Should also make sure Windows 'fast boot' is disabled, and am thinking your Windows might have dynamic partition instead of basic.

Comment: See also:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 2):

Your Ubuntu installation should have the `ext4` file system.

EFI is a system partition that should already exist if you have UEFI compatible firmware and Windows is installed using UEFI.

FAT32 is unable to handle UNIX permissions or ownership, so you can't use Ubuntu on a FAT32 file system.